# How to find the equivalent delphi function of the c++ functions in msdn?

Tags: delphi

The Microsoft Developer Network MSDN is full of useful documented functions that are a necessity to learn about and to stay updated with for a windows app developer.

For example the shellexecute function in [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762153(v=vs.85).aspx) is well documented (translated below by Embarcadero Technologies).

```
function ShellExecute; external shell32 name 'ShellExecuteW';
```

However the language used to explain these functions is c/c++ (not complaining or any thing).

To find where is the equivalent to these functions (if it exist or not is another question) can be hard.

For example I'm looking for the equivalent of this [function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365866(v=vs.85).aspx):

```
DWORD CreateIpNetEntry(
  _In_ PMIB_IPNETROW pArpEntry
);
```

Now it would be pointless to always come and ask here where I can find the equivalent each time I get stuck. So my question is:

Is there a way to know if there is an equivalent/translation to the c++ functions at MSDN in delphi and where to find them(the unit)?

Comment: Try [JEDI headers](https://sourceforge.net/projects/jedi-apilib/) (in this case the function in [JwaIpHlpApi.pas](https://sourceforge.net/p/jedi-apilib/code/HEAD/tree/jwapi/trunk/Win32API/JwaIpHlpApi.pas#l254) and the used structure in [JwaIpRtrMib.pas](https://sourceforge.net/p/jedi-apilib/code/HEAD/tree/jwapi/trunk/Win32API/JwaIpRtrMib.pas#l785)). Many of prototypes translated there were more accurate than those shipped with Delphi.

Comment: @Victoria Thanks it is the first time I hear about it

Comment: You're welcome and sorry. I misunderstood your question.

Comment: As answers state, grepping gives ultimate result. But first give a chance to the unit that's the translation of the library: scroll to bottom on MSDN and find that it's in "Iphlpapi", paste it into "uses", ctrl+enter, and search the function.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz working like a charm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find whether or not a particular API function has been translated by simply searching the Delphi source folder for it.

Any search in files tool will serve the necessary purpose, including the built-in [Find in Files](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Find_in_Files).

Comment: "Find in Files" works really well for me for years .

Comment: @kobik, Find in Files is for included files (or files in included subdirectories). That requires Delphi source files of course.

Comment: That's true, without the source then you are stuck. But if you have the source then this is certainly the most reliable way.

Comment: @Victoria, I really can't imagine developing in Delphi without source files. I really suffer when I develop in .NET for this reason (with constant need to use reflection).

Comment: @kobik, me too. I was just trying to address trial avids. Maybe it has opposite effect in the end.

Comment: I'm choosing this one because it is the most reliable when you have the source code. The other answer also gives the unit name along some others that don't have the function (I think it is a bug). How ever I would like to note that the trick given by @ Sertac Akyuz (pasting the name of the c++ unit name in the uses clause and pressing Ctrl+Enter) is also a working like a charm solution.

Answer (score 4):

This is described in [**Finding Units**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Finding_Units_(Delphi)) topic:

> Editing Delphi code in the **Code Editor**, you can use the **Find Unit**
>   refactoring dialog box to locate and add units to your code. The **Find
>   Unit** dialog appears when you select an identifier in the **Code Editor**
>   and select the **Refactor > Find Unit** menu command. The operation
>   attempts to find the appropriate unit containing the definition of the
>   selected identifier, and then adds the selected unit to the uses
>   clause. You can select multiple units to add to the uses clause. To
>   find and add a unit to the uses clause:
>
> 1. In the **Code Editor**, click an identifier whose unit you want to add to the uses clause.
> 2. Choose the **Refactor > Find Unit** menu command. The **Find Unit** dialog box displays a selection list of applicable Delphi units.
> 3. Select the unit that you want to add to the uses clause in the current scope. You can select as many units as you want.
> 4. Choose where to insert the reference, either in the **interface** section or in the **implementation** section.
> 5. Click **OK**. The uses clause is updated with the selected units.

Or you can grep the Delphi source folder if you have Delphi with source code.

Comment: Writing the function's name in the search box for step 3 seems to work fine.

Comment: My first attempt to use this refactoring tool led to this error: *System.OutOfMemoryException: Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.* That was fixed by a restart. After that the refactoring tool worked, but failed to find the function `CreateIpNetEntry` even though a translation exists. Conclusion, don't use this tool. Use search instead.

Comment: @David, wow, that it fails for you is conclusion? What if you have Starter?

Comment: @Victoria Forgive me for preferring to use a tool that actually works. I type `CreateIpNetEntry` into the code editor, invoke the Find Unit command, and nothing is found.

Comment: @David, it sounds like "conclusion for all". This refactoring tool works fine for me. I don't know about this problem, but do you use e.g. IDE Fix Pack? Also keep in mind, that if you were using Starter edition, you cannot grep the source because it comes without source, hence this refactoring tool can be your "last chance" to find the declaration :)

Comment: I do use IDE Fix Pack. This tool manages to find that function if I add the unit where it lives to the uses clause. Kinda defeats the purpose. I don't really trust the Emba refactoring tools. Too many bugs over the years. When I search for something I want to be able to trust the results. I think we all know that Find in Files, or good old grep work reliably.